# PostgreSQL: how do I query over a column with a custom range?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a query over a string column called `grades_served` that can have values such as

```
k-5
1-5
5-9
```

The query could be for a specific grade or it could be a range with a start and end value.

I wanted to check what the best approach would be on this. My gut instinct tells me to reformat the column into a range datatype, but the issue is this is a complex range, with string values, such as k and Pre-K.

I thought about creating a custom type but that seems like an overkill and I've never done that before.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtype.html

Would really appreciate any thoughts or recommendations.

Comment: Use an enum, sounds like an ideal candidate.

Answer (score 4):

The range type would allow best performance and simple queries.

If you have some string values like `k` and `Pre-K` mixed with numeric values, just create a grade table with a rank value (an integer value representing actual sort order):

```
CREATE TABLE grade(
   grade text PRIMARY KEY
  ,grade_int UNIQUE int NOT NULL
);
```

Your numeric grades can conveniently be assigned the same `grade_value`, other grades get integer values according to their rank.

You might write a simple function to convert ranges with your original string values to their integer representations on the fly ...
And vice-versa to display your `grades_served` column where needed.

Convert `grades_served` to an [`int4range`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html) type.
Using the [overlap operator `&&`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE), your query for a *range of grades* can then simply be:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE grades_served && '[1,4]'::int4range;
```

Or, for a *single grade*, the "contains element" operator `@>`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE grades_served @> -1;
```

#### Index

If your table is not very small I suggest you create a GiST index to support that ([and so does the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING)).

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_grades_served_idx ON tbl USING gist (grades_served);
```