# Selecting only overlapping elements from array of ranges

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, array, set-returning-functions, range-types

The table I need to search contains an array of numrange values illustrated by:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( sensor varchar(25), ranges numrange[] );
INSERT INTO data VALUES
  ('sensor0','{"[872985609.0,873017999.0]","[873021600.0,873035999.0]","[873039600.0,873072070.0]"}'::numrange[])
, ('sensor1','{"[872929250.000000,872985609.000000]"}'::numrange[]);
```

Searching for rows with elements in `ranges` that overlap a specified range is easy with `ANY`:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE '[873021700,873021800]'::numrange && ANY (ranges)
```

I would like a SELECT statement that returns fields from the table along with *only* elements from the array that overlap a specified range, aka:

```
SELECT sensor,[array of overlapping numranges] FROM data WHERE '[873021700,873021800]'::numrange && ANY (ranges)
```

resulting in:

```
sensor      ranges
sensor0     {"[873021600.0,873035999.0]"}
```

Is this possible without `unnest()`ing the array in a subselect?  If not, what would be an efficient way to `unnest()` when the arrays are potentially very large?

Comment: So you want the intersection of your range with each range in the table? Returning one row for each intersection value?

Comment: @JoshRagem, not a row for each intersection or overlap, which, in my real use case, would result in a huge number of duplicated fields also being extracted.  To reduce the duplication I'd like the matching ranges to be returned as an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works as desired:

```
SELECT d.sensor, r.overlapping_ranges
FROM   data d
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(range) AS overlapping_ranges
   FROM   unnest(d.ranges) range
   WHERE  range && '[873021700,873021800]'::numrange 
   ) r ON overlapping_ranges IS NOT NULL;
```

About `LATERAL`:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

For big tables, it would be much more efficient to normalize your design with a separate `ranges` table (one range per row) instead of the ranges array. You can use a GiST index for that:

- [PostgreSQL: how do I query over a column with a custom range?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69799/postgresql-how-do-i-query-over-a-column-with-a-custom-range/69841#69841)
- [2 B-tree indices OR 1 GiST index on tsrange -- which will perform better?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59074/2-b-tree-indices-or-1-gist-index-on-tsrange-which-will-perform-better/59083#59083)

---

### Solution for huge table

For a huge table like you mention in the comments (1 billion rows) I would consider a separate `ranges` table, optimized for size and a [**BRIN index**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#BRIN_Indexes) to go along with it.

Assuming:

- Read only (or mostly) data.
- A maximum of 6 fractional digits (*scale*) and a maximum of 18 digits total (*precision*). Scaled by 1000000, this fits into a `bigint` without loss, which is considerably cheaper to store. See below.
- Postgres 9.5 or later.

The [operator class for range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/brin-builtin-opclasses.html#BRIN-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE) shipped with Postgres 9.5 is `range_inclusion_ops`, which supports the overlaps operator `&&`.

To optimize disk space some more I would just save ***two `bigint` numbers*** (your numeric values multiplied by 1000000) and make it a functional BRIN index. Basically like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sensors (
  sensor_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, sensor text NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE ranges (
  sensor_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES sensors
, range_low bigint NOT NULL
, range_hi  bigint NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO sensors (sensor) VALUES ('sensor1');

INSERT INTO ranges (sensor_id, range_low, range_hi) VALUES
   (1, 872985609.0 * 1000000, 873017999.0 * 1000000)  -- scaled
 , (1, 872929250.000000 * 1000000, 872985609.000000 * 1000000);

CREATE INDEX ranges_brin_idx ON ranges USING BRIN (int8range(range_low, range_hi, '[]'));
```

**Query** to get the same result as before:

```
SELECT s.sensor, r.ranges
FROM  (
   SELECT sensor_id
        , array_agg(numrange(range_low * .000001, range_hi * .000001, '[]')) AS ranges
   FROM   ranges
   WHERE  int8range(range_low, range_hi, '[]')
       && '[873021700000000,873021800000000]'::int8range  -- scaled as well
   GROUP  BY sensor_id
   ) r
JOIN   sensors s  USING (sensor_id);
```

#### Storage size of `bigint` vs. `numrange`

A `numrange` with numbers of 15 precision occupies 32 bytes on disk, 
resulting in 64 bytes per row (plus int column, tuple header and item identifier).

While the same with two `bigint` columns (2 x 8 bytes) results in 52 bytes total. Makes the table around **12 GB smaller**. Index size is the same.

See for yourself:

```
SELECT pg_column_size((1::bigint, '[873021700.123456,873021800.123456]'::numrange))
     , pg_column_size((1::bigint, 873021700123456::bigint, 873021700123456::bigint));
```

Detailed explanation for row size:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Comment: Thanks!  This works and I learned about LATERAL.  A redesign might be possible in the future.  The [Tip in the array docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) stating: "Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. ..." is right inline with what you write.  Thanks for the doc pointers.

Comment: In my real case other fields in the table are used to pare down the rows that the LATERAL operates on.  The total number of ranges is just over 1 billion, spread among 10s of thousands of rows.  So while the `unnest()` is definitely the slowest part of this query, creating a separate `ranges` table with a billion rows will be a challenge too.

Comment: @terse: My first idea for such a huge table is a BRIN index. I added a prototype solution above.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts on a big table design, much appreciated.